# angular to server bind not working with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got an angular question i have a project with a simple controller that loads data from the server
I'd like to validate the data and change its display by its validation
I'm using a directive and not a filter for that for 2 reasons
1. I'm changing the DOM and that is in my opinion more a directive job
2. Performance.

I've asked before on the issue of the directive vs the filter and both I and the commentators got to the idea that a directive is more suitable.

Now I have this problem,
when loading a single object from the server and setting it to a single $scope property. the directive does not set with its value
but when using an array with ng-repeat, all is working well.
the question is why and what do you think should be the best approach

a demo code for both tests

```
app.controller('controller1',['$scope', 'HttpService', function($scope, HttpService) {
    HttpService.get().success(function(data) {
        $scope.item = data;
        $scope.item[0] = data;
    });
}]);

app.directive('directive1', ['ValdataionService' , function (ValdataionService){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var input = attrs.validateData;

            if(ValdataionService.isValid(input)) {
                elem.html('<div class="success">' + input + '</div>');
            } else {
                elem.html('<div class="error">' + input + '</div>');
            }
        }
     }
 }]);


 /* HTML */

 <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK -->
 <div directive1 validate-data="{{item.input}}"></div>

 <!-- THIS DOES WORK -->
 <div ng-repeat="it in items">
     <div directive1 validate-data="{{it.input}}"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "why" is probably the simpler question to answer. The ng-repeat doesn't actually start adding to the DOM until there is data in your array.

I was able to "move" a few things around and get it to work on my end.  I think you should consider putting the conditional expression within a template in the directive instead of adding html directly through the link function. Also try adding the validateData var to the directive private scope and setting up some binding.

```
scope:{
validateData: ''
},
template:'<html code here>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgbavgej/

Comment: Don't know if your demo is exactly as using the $http to call the server, because $time is part of the angular context while the $http response is not.